# Vanish div element if its empty

Tags: html, css

I put data inside `<div>` element like this

```
echo '<div class="blue">'.$row['exp'].'</div>';
```

Sometimes `$row['exp']` is empty. However it still show its 1px border as a point. How can i vanish it completely.

Here is my  [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2196rz7/1/)

Comment: div:empty { display: none; }. See https://jsfiddle.net/68nsrctf/

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `:empty` CSS selector for that.
Like this

```
 div:empty {
   display: none;
 }
```

Or you can just not `echo` the html if the row is empty

Answer (score 2):

Here's the alternative method:

```
if (!empty($row['exp'])) { 
    echo '<div class="blue">'.$row['exp'].'</div>';
}
```